# How to reset Exchange message throttling

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013, exchange-2016

I have a user account that I believe Exchange has throttled outgoing email as it may have been picked up as spamming user accounts (large bulk email) - On the Queue viewer the error for the emails are 45 - You have exceeded your permitted sending rate for 451 (email address).

How do i reset the limitation on this account?

Answer (score 1):

By Default limit is 20
**Use Command :**

To create a new policy where the users can send to 30 recipients a day and no more than 1 message per minute, you would use this command:

New-ThrottlingPolicy -Name LimitMessagesSent -RecipientRateLimit 30 -MessageRateLimit 1